# Center a glyph and text vertically in a button with Bootstrap 3

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm trying to get a glyph and a bootstrap 3 dropdown component to work nicely together. My html looks like this:

```
<div class="btn-group">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
    Make you selection
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down pull-right"></span>
  </button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li><a href="#">Dropdown link</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Dropdown link</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Dropdown link</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

I have added a glpyhicon inside the button and this works fine in Chrome:

[image: Dropdown in chrome]
If I look at the page in Firefox the glyph and text are not aligning at all:

[image: Dropdown in Firefox]

Here is a live version of the code: http://www.bootply.com/116794

Why is this not aligning properly in Firefox? How can I get the text and glyph aligned vertically centered in both browsers?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because your misusing `.pull-right`. Wrap your text in a span, and put your floating element **before** this span :

```
<div class="btn-group">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down pull-right"></span> <!-- moved -->
    <span>Make your selection</span> <!-- wrapped -->
  </button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li><a href="#">Dropdown link</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Dropdown link</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Dropdown link</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Dropdown link</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Dropdown link</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Dropdown link</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Dropdown link</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Dropdown link</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

[**Updated Bootply**](http://www.bootply.com/116841)

Comment: Thanks, this works. Why should I not be using the pull-right like this? I've basically copied it from the BS3 docs for button dropdowns I only changed the caret to a glyph and tried to move it to the right: <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
    Action <span class="caret"></span>
  </button>

Comment: In BS3 example, caret is not floating. Making it floating break everything because there's no refered element (I should float, ok, but near what ?). That's why I wrapped the text and reversed the order. Now, the icon know it should float to the right of the next element : the text.

Comment: Great, that makes sense. Strange though that Chrome renders it fine and Firefox not.

Comment: According to my tests wrapping the text with an additional span is not necessary. Simply moving the glyphicon in front is the key to solve that FF problem.